# How to change flashvarsObj

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I can set flashvarsObj on initialization (swfobject.embedSWF) , but don't know how to change flashvarsObj after initialization when I access to it by swfobject.getObjectById.

I have a flash graph and I need to reload it with new parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlashVars are only passed at the moment the file is embedded. If you need to pass new vars, you must either delete then re-embed the entire SWF, or modify your SWF to use [ExternalInterface](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/external-interface/) for passing data via JavaScript.

Comment: yep, modifying is the solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain you have to re-invoke the embedSWF method all over again. An existing flash swf can't just dynamically change flashvars unless perhaps you attach a method to the swf that is callable by the Javascript which passes vars to it.